# Prevent page from fully loading in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to keep a webpage in a loading state?

I thought of sending resource request to web server and making the web server not send anything back. However I would like to find a solution that can be controlled from the client side.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am looking at building a PWA with a service worker that caches everything and then loads based on that cache. At the moment I can either load the page and have the service worker cache (which downloads the source files twice) or I can have a simple page with only the service worker that caches and then after caching all resources reloads the page using the cache (more efficient)... However when the html page loads the browser stops loading and the user can't see that the service worker is downloading in the background. I would like it to continue to show loading until I say it's finished.

Comment: When you use the option to first load a simple page which then loads from the cache can't you implement a custom loader? Maybe make it nice with a splashscreen and a loading message/bar?

Comment: I could. But I am looking for this particular solution.